# Why Object.prototype.__proto__ === null

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

In JavaScript non-standard property __ proto__ and function Object.getPrototypeOf (...) return the internal property [[Prototype]].

For all functions the property 'prototype' is an instance of Object.prototype, for example:

```
Array.prototype instanceof Object//true
```

But not so with Object.prototype:

```
Object.prototype.__proto__ === null //true
Object.getPrototypeOf( Object.prototype ) === null //true
```

[mozilla developer documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) only says:

> An Object's **proto** property references the same object as its
>   internal [[Prototype]] (often referred to as "the prototype"), which
>   may be an object or, as in the default case of
>   Object.prototype.**proto**, null .

Would it be more appropiate that Object.prototype.**proto** or failing Object.getPrototypeOf (Object.prototype) return Object.prototype?

Is this a bug? Is this ok? why?

Comment: Why would you expect that?

Comment: Step 4 of [`[[GetProperty]]`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.2) would never be true, so looking for a nonexistent property would cause an infinite loop over `Object.prototype`. The step tests for a null prototype, signifying the top of the prototype chain; without a `null` prototype, the chain ends with a loop.

Answer (score 5):

The prototype chain has to stop somewhere.

Had `Object.getPrototypeOf( Object.prototype ) === Object.prototype`, the JS engine would get into an infinite loop when it tries to resolve something from the prototype.

It would walk up the prototype chain to `Object.prototype`, and, if it doesn't find it there, it would walk further up to `Object.prototype` again, *ad infinitum*.

In fact, if you try to do that yourself, you'll get an error:

```
> Object.prototype.__proto__ = Object.prototype
Error: Cyclic __proto__ value
```

---

Note that you can also create your own objects with no `[[Prototype]]` by calling `Object.create(null)`.

Answer (score 1):

While `Object.prototype.__proto__` is supported today in most browsers, its existence and exact behavior has only been standardized in the ECMAScript 2015 specification as a legacy feature to ensure compatibility for web browsers. For better support, use Object.getPrototypeOf() instead.

link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto